# Amazanon MySQL RDS - failing to connect (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003])

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to RDS from Amazon cloud instance, and I keep getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxx' (4)
```

I am able to connect to the RDS via MySQL Workbench without any problems, but when I try to connect from instance, the error occurs. This is the code for connecting to the RDS:

```
$this->_host     = 'xxx';
        $this->_user     = 'xxx';
        $this->_password = 'xxx';
        $this->_dbname   = 'xxx';

        $dns = 'mysql:host=' . $this->_host . ';dbname=' . $this->_dbname . ';port=3306';

        $options = array(
            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $this->handler = new \PDO($dns, $this->_user, $this->_password, $options);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
           die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Your host is bad. Are you sure of $this->_host ?

Comment: Yea - it is copy/paste from Amazon RDS console. Also I am using same data for MySQL workbench and I am not getting any error.

Comment: It might be that the server is running, but you are trying to connect using a TCP/IP port different from the one on which the server is listening and what are you getting at place of 'xxxx'  in Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxx'

Comment: Is this error immediate, or delayed by a few seconds?